# using CreateProcess with a relative path

Tags: c++, windows, process, winapi

Is it possible to pass a relative path to create my child process?
This code will compile, but it gives an error because I'm using a relative path.

```
void Cminivideo3App::creerChildProcess(void)
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

    // Start the child process. 
  int retvalue =   CreateProcess( TEXT("\..\Debug\traitement.exe"),   // No module name (use command line)
        NULL,        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi            // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    );

  int lastError = GetLastError();


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couple things:

1. As @Oswald says, `\` is the root folder of the current drive, not a relative path.
2. You forgot to escape your backslashes. You really want `TEXT("..\\Debug\\traitement.exe")`.

Comment: For some reason today it worked. I had given up on child processes and I was using Visual Studio to start both projects. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

It does not look like a relative path to me. `\` is the root folder of the current drive.